# subscribe to image topic over WiFi

Tags: ros, wifi, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I have an Asctec Pelican here with a Ueye camera attached to it. We're trying to set it up such that we can subscribe to the topic from a remote PC, and view the video feed in real time.

We set up a local WiFi network, and experienced tons of latency and very low framerate. We verified that the images are published at the desired rate on the Asctec itself, so it seems like it's either Asctec or WiFi bandwidth that's causing the issue.

Has any of you tried this type of things before?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36829/subscribe-to-image-topic-over-wifi/) by [yan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2654/yan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should try the following:

`rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image _image_transport:=theora`

...with `/camera/image` the image topic you want to display. Using image transport decreases a lot the bandwith required by the streaming, but it requires CPU power to compress the data on your robot.

The only other option is to stream *different* data: lower resolution, black and white only, etc.

PS: yes, wifi router usually behaves very badly when they reach theirs limits. Freeze, bad performances, reboot, etc. So what you experience is probably an access point performance issue.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2